# Can I customize error reports in Gatling?

Tags: karate

Using Karate-Gatling, the default reports I get only log errors as

```
path/to/feature/myFeature.feature:19 method get
```

If I read the feature file, I can find the offending line and determine the cause of the error. However I would like to have this information in the report itself (so my colleagues and I don't have to go fishing through the features).

Is there a way to add a custom error log into the Gatling report? Possibly replace the location (`path/to/feature/myFeature.feature:19 method get`) with a custom message?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can consider contributing code. There may be an opportunity to emit the Karate HTML reports only on errors. But right now, for performance reasons, all the reporting is disabled when in "gatling mode".